# How to calculate size of all node_modules installed on macOS?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm looking for a simple command to run calculate size of all node_modules install globally (not the ones located in projects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using using nvm:

find ~/.nvm  -type d -name 'node_modules' | xargs du -csh | grep total

You can change up the find command if your not using nvm, or you want to include projects as well. If you want to find where global node_modules are located run npm list -g and it will tell you where the packages are located.

Answer (score 12):

I was curious about this too. This command should work:

```sh
find . -type d -name node_modules -prune | tr '\n' '\0' |  xargs -0 du -sch
```

Quick explanation (updated 2021-11):

1. The first part is easy, `find . -type d -name node_modules` finds every directory `-type d` named `node_modules` below the current directory `.` The `-prune` flag prevents descending into matched paths, so nested directories like `site/node_modules/some-lib/node_modules` will be hidden.
2. <s>We only want the first `node_modules`, so an inverse grep `grep -v node_modules.*node_modules`  strips out every matched path containing more than one `node_modules`.</s> (removed in favor of find's faster `-prune` flag.)
3. The `tr '\n' '\0'` command is only here to keep the following `xargs` command from choking on filenames with spaces or special characters. This replaces the normal line-returns `\n` with ASCII NUL `\0` characters.
4. Finally,  `xargs -0 du -sch` collects everything into an argument list and passes the result to `du -sch` which reports disk usage for each entry and a cumulative total using "human-readable" output.

I found just over 6 GB of assorted `node_modules` directories in my projects folder.

Comment: I, too, had over 6 GB accumulated.  Then I ran `find . -type d -name node_modules |  grep -v node_modules.*node_modules | tr '\n' '\0' |  xargs -0 rm -rf`

Answer (score 1):

I use this command `find . -name "node_modules" -type d -prune -print | xargs du -chs`